# Using Django model's post_save for manual cache invalidation: do foreign keys trigger save()?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-models, django-signals

This seems like a pretty simple question but I'm having trouble finding the answer to it:

Do Django models with a foreign key ever call the save() method of the model they're pointing to when *they* are saved/changed?

I'm working on a model for SAT exams being taken, graded and scored--the last of which involves caching and cache invalidation--and trying to figure out just when I have to delete a cached Score object and recalculate it.

I have three models: ExamResponse, QuestionResponse, and ExamScore, which for concreteness we can say look like this:

```
class ExamResponse(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam)

class QuestionResponse(models.Model):
    exam_response = models.ForeignKey(ExamResponse)
    answer = models.TextField()
    score = models.smallIntegerField(default=0)

class ExamScore(models.Model):
    exam_response = models.ForeignKey(ExamResponse)
    score = models.smallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Whenever a teacher grades an QuestionResponse (by changing the score field), I want to delete any ExamScore associated with the QuestionResponse's ExamResponse.  Can I listen for a signal from a change to an ExamResponse object?

```
@receiver(post_save, model=ExamResponse)
def invalidate_exam_response_stats(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Delete the ExamScore associated with this ExamResponse
    since it's become invalid.
    """
```

Or do I have to listen for the actual QuestionResponses to be saved?

```
@receiver(post_save, model=QuestionResponse)
def invalidate_exam_response_stats(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Look up the QuestionResponse's ExamResponse, then delete
    the associated ExamScore.
    """
```

Comment: What's the problem? a circular execution?

Comment: What?  No... the problem is uncertainty over whether ExamResponse's post_save signal will be sent when something with an fk to it is saved

Comment: @brendan if `FK` of a model is updated, signals are not triggered for that model.

Comment: @ozgur which is the same as if *something with an `FK` to a* model is updated, signals are not triggered for that model, right?

Comment: Also, @ozgur why not post an answer to answer the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: no, they do not do that.

I should listen to the QuestionResponse objects.

Thanks @ozgur for this answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer your own question since you got your answer in comments. It really does help to make the site better. Don't forget to come back and accept your own answer in a day or so!